# TreeView MVVM, how to get selection?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to create a `TreeView` for my application. This is the first time I am using `TreeView` with the MVVM structure, by all accounts the binding is working and displaying correctly.

### However:

**How do I get the selection so I can perform some logic after the user selects something?**

I thought that the `TextValue` property in `SubSection class`  would fire `PropertyChanged`, but it doesn't, so I am left scratching my head.

---

This is the most simplified set of code I could make for this question:

Using `PropertyChanged` setup like this in : `ViewModelBase` `class`

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

The VeiwModel:

```
public class ShiftManagerViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{

    public ShiftManagerViewModel()
    {
        Departments = new List<Department>()
        {
            new Section("Section One"),
            new Section("Section Two")
        };
    }

    private List<Section> _sections;

    public List<Section> Sections
    {
        get{return _sections;}
        set
        {
            _sections = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The classes:

```
public class Section : ViewModelBase
{
    public Section(string depname)
    {
        DepartmentName = depname;
        Courses = new List<SubSection>()
        {
            new SubSection("SubSection One"),
            new SubSection("SubSection One")
        };
    }

    private List<SubSection> _courses;
    public List<SubSection> Courses
    {
        get{ return _courses; }
        set
        {
            _courses = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

public class SubSection : ViewModelBase
{
    public SubSection(string coursename)
    {
        CourseName = coursename;
    }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    private string _vTextValue;

    public string TextValue
    {
        get { return _vTextValue; }
        set
        {
            _vTextValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:Section}">
        <Label Content="{Binding DepartmentName}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding TextValue}" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SubSection}">
        <Label Content="{Binding CourseName}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "user selects something" == `TreeView.SelectedItem` changes. create a binding between `TreeView.SelectedItem` and top-level-viewModel property and perform some logic in setter of that property

Comment: @ASh, that is what I thought of too, but there is no `SelectedItem` to bind to in `HierarchicalDataTemplate` ??? Thanks

Comment: `TreeView.SelectedItem` : `<TreeView SelectedItem="{Binding Path=???}" ...`

Comment: @ASh, I have been looking for that and the only thing close is `SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=???}` and that obviously does not work.

Comment: [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Who made `TreeView` readonly, I want to punch them in the face right now. Grrrr.

Comment: Is the name `PropertyChangedNotify` a typo? Because per `INotifyPropertyChanged` (which your view model should implement) the event should be called `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Grx70, whoops, yes that is.

Comment: OK, I have seem to be able to get the the selected `Object`, but I don't know how to get the object name? How dose one go about that?

Comment: Sometimes it's worth to have an `bool IsSelected` property on every item VM and bind to `TreeViewItem.IsSelected`. Otherwise, the `TreeView.SelectedItem` can be readonly-bound with an attached property. A read-write binding is pretty complicated in a nested treeview.

Comment: @grek40, I managed to get the `bool IsSelected` and I created an `Object` which holds all the information about what has been selected. In the intellisence, when holding the mouse over the `Object` it shows its `string` name value among other things. How do I get that `string` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the `SelectedItem` property of the `TreeView` to a `Section` or a `SubSection` or whatever the type of the selected item is:

```
Section section = treeView1.SelectedItem as Section;
if (section != null)
{
    //A Section is selected. Access any of its properties here
    string name = section.DepartmentName;
}
else
{
    SubSection ss = treeView1.SelectedItem as SubSection;
    if(ss != null)
    {
        string ssName = ss.CourseName;
    }
}
```

Or you could add an `IsSelected` property to the `Section` and `SubSection` types and bind the `IsSelected` property of the `TreeView` to it:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then you get the selected item by iterating through the `ItemsSource` of the `TreeView` and look for the item that has the `IsSelected` source property set to true.

Comment: That was pretty much the XAML I used to get the `IsSelected` property, but could I ask where `treeView1` is? Does this mean you named the `TreeView` control `treeView1`? Cheers

Comment: OK, that worked. I named the `Treeview` and initialized in the mainwindow as a static property and used it in the viewmodel. Cheers.